# How to create realistic alien evolution in a swampy planet? (Like dagobah from Star Wars)

Tags: internal-consistency, evolution, xenobiology

Essentially, I’m curious to know what would be the most likely (semi-complex, multicellular) animal lifeforms to develop on planets with gravity similar to Mars and Earth.

Comment: Your title question is not a question and your main body does not have a question mark.

Comment: I have voted to close for now. The question can definitely be a good one, but currently can be answered with a list. Anything not human and still complex is valid, making it even a rather long list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, roaches, kind of like District 9. They would be intelligent enough and have many usable limbs. This question is kind of vague so almost anything can work here, even a blob-person.

Answer (score 1):

**Crabs**

[image]

Crabs have evolved on Earth several times. A process called carcinisation.

[image]

I guess that means if life evolved on Mars it . . . MIGHT be crabs.

Comment: @LittlePickle. It is more specific than Convergent Evolution.

Comment: It took a while, but I got it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the ocotopi!

They are highly intelligent, by some measures of problem solving they are smarter than six-year-old humans.

And completely alien to humans. Five lobed brains, 8 arms that each have mini-brains of their own, they reproduce differently, master manipulators with there arms and individually controlled suckers, and on and on.

Octopi would be an excellent starting point for aliens.

(In the current series "Resident Alien", the alien is descended from octopi.)

Answer (score 1):

You should exlain what you want in more detail.  YOur question as it is worded now, 2:26 pm EST on May 7, 2022, is vague enough to have several possible meanings.

Do you plaln to create a planet wth only one species of complex plant or animal life, or a planet with thousands or millions of species of complex plant and animal equvalent lifeforms?

Do you want to create a complex alien animal that is many times as intelligent as the least intelligent multicelled animals but only a fraction as intelligent as humans, or do you want to create a complex alien species of intelligent beings?

I note that if you want to create a realkistic and plausible species of intelligent but non humanoid aliens, the logical thing to do would be to make them similar to species on Earth which are considered most likely to have human or near human intelligence levels.